# The requested URL /xampp/ was not found on this server.

Tags: apache2, xampp

I have a running `XAMPP(lampp)` in the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp` directory.

I have downloaded `xampp 1.8.2-4` from [here](http://www.apachefriends.org)

I start xampp by `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start/stop` so whenever I hit localhost it redirects me to `localhost/xampp`

Now the problem is when I hit `localhost/xampp` its showing

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /xampp/ was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

the problem is my localhost is now pointing to `/var/www/index.html` not to `/opt` directory

Apache is starting when I type in the terminal:

```
$ service apache2 start
* Starting web server apache2
```

Now, after stopping XAMPP by

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

when i hit `localhost` its fetching `index.html` from `var/www` directory with a message

> It works!
>   This is the default web page for this server.
>   The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

How can I make my `XAMPP` responds with

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

How it can be resolved?

Comment: As mentioned in the [tag excerpt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xampp) `XAMPP is NOT packaged in Ubuntu! Installing LAMP, which consists of the same components, is recommended instead and as easy as installing XAMPP`

Answer (score 1):

You must change `DocumentRoot` in `VirtualHost`

File is `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin web@your_site.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/your_site"
    ServerName your_site.com
    ErrorLog "logs/your_site.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/your_site.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: httpd-vhost.conf got two <virtualhost> segment.can u plz elaborate where to change to responds with localhost/xampp

Comment: Edit one segment or you can add new sector <virtualhost> with your data